# Remove ?autoplay=1 with a javascript .replace()

Tags: javascript, regex

A get some URLs with the `?autoplay=1` in it I would like to do a `str.replace()` to remove this `?autoplay=1` from the url.

For now I have something like this which isn't working

`val.replace('/(?autoplay=1)/g','');`

Sometime I have an url with multiple `?autplay=1` so a regex that will remove all occurence of this pattern could be appreciated

Comment: Do you have multiple times ?autoplay=1 or are the others &autoplay=1? in general you should only have ONE '?' to start the query string, with '&' separating the parts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`?` is special meta character in regex so you need to escape it. Also regex literal in Javascript should not be quoted:

```
val = val.replace(/\?autoplay=1/g, '');
```

To also match `autplay` use:

```
val = val.replace(/\?auto?play=1\b/g, '');
```

`\b` is for word boundary so that it doesn't match `?autoplay=10` for example.

Though keep in mind if your URL is:

```
foo.bar?autoplay=1&otherparam=123
```

then it will become:

```
foo.bar&otherparam=123
```

Comment: Also it might not be the best to remove it like  that... What if there is more in the query? Then it will be like this `foo.bar&otherparam=...` which wouldn't work.

Comment: I agree, let me add this in my answer.